# Jquery Mobile Image Upload with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app using jquery mobile and i am at the point or making a select image and upload feature. I am using this function to show the image that the user selects in a div :

```
function displayAsImage3(file, containerid) {
        if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
            var container = document.getElementById(containerid),
                img = document.createElement("img"),
                reader;
            container.appendChild(img);
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theImg) {
                return function (evt) {
                    theImg.src = evt.target.result;
                };
            }(img));
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```

I have read a lot about jquery mobile and uploading images, how can i send this image to the server, do i need to convert the img? use ajax? save to a database? save to a dir? please can someone assist me with what i need to do to get this image saved somewhere on my server.

Thanks

Comment: I would like to save the image as a blob in the database

Comment: Don't save images as blobs in databases. That's horribly inefficient. Yes, you'd need to use AJAX to submit it to a PHP (or other server-side) script that saves it to the server's filesystem.